# Splash screen doesn't hide - using Microsoft.VisualBasic library

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2 forms. Form1 (with code below) and Splash (just default form for test).

My problem is that after application run the Splash doesn't hide. Main form is loaded but Splash is still not closed.

The **Form1** code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    class Program : WindowsFormsApplicationBase 
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            //Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            //Application.Run(new Form1());

            // Show Form in Single-instance mode
            var prg = new Program();
            prg.EnableVisualStyles = true;
            prg.IsSingleInstance = true;
            prg.MinimumSplashScreenDisplayTime = 1000;
            prg.SplashScreen = new Splash();
            prg.MainForm = new Form1();
            prg.Run(args);
        }
    }
}
```

You must add reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic to work of this.

**Splash** form code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Splash : Form
    {
        public Splash()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah you're using the Visual Basic Appplication Framework to run the splash screen?
Try this.
This is from a quick Forms application - note that I have left all names and namespace as default, so you may need to change this for your code. The project has two forms only. Form2 is the splash screen. I embedded a background image on it in order to ensure that it popped up okay and that I could differentiate it from Form1.

I added a reference to .NET Microsoft.VisualBasic into my project.

This is from the program.cs file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            new MyApp().Run(args);
        }
    }
    public class MyApp : WindowsFormsApplicationBase
    {
        protected override void OnCreateSplashScreen()
        {
            this.SplashScreen = new Form2();
        }
        protected override void OnCreateMainForm()
        {
            // Do your initialization here
            //...
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);  // Test
            // Then create the main form, the splash screen will automatically close
            this.MainForm = new Form1();
        }
    }
}
```

I know that is different to wht you're using but it seems to work.

Comment: Thank you very much, you direct me on a good way. I just added to your code:
        public MyApp()
        {
            this.IsSingleInstance = true;
        }

plus override OnStartupNextInstance

and now I have all what I need. Single-instance app and Splash screen.
Thanks!