# Creating splashscreen without creating multi-threading form

Tags: c#

I want to make a splash screen without creating multi-threading on the application does anybody have any idea to create splash screen that will automatically show the next form?

I have trying this timer_tick and creating object to showdialog for the next form but it doesn't work properly.

Comment: If you want to wait a specific amount of seconds, and show the new form then, a timer is a proper way.
Please share your code...

Comment: This is my code for timer tick : `progressbar1.increment (1); if(progressbar1.value==100) { timer1.stop(); form2 frm = new form2(); frm.shows(); this.close;}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
public partial class FormTicker : Form
{
    Timer timer;
    public FormTicker()
    {
        timer = new Timer();
        InitializeComponent();
        timer.Interval = 2000;
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
        timer.Start();
    }

    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Stop();
        FormMain formMain = new FormMain();
        formMain.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Visual Basic has support for splash screens that you can take advantage of by referencing Microsoft.VisualBasic in your c# project.

An example can be found at [Splash screen doesn't hide - using Microsoft.VisualBasic library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253020/splash-screen-doesnt-hide-using-microsoft-visualbasic-library)